# Laravel not returning controller

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have a simple ajax() get request that's supposed to add a coupon if they choose to accept it (via a pop up with an a tag). However, when I run the page and I click on the a tag and look at it in the console all it's doing is returning the entire page in HTML. How can I get it to properly use the controller I specify via routes? I am new to Ajax so I am sure that's where the problem is. So what's supposed to happen is the customer clicks on the accept coupon button, ajax processes the information with the controller and then shows another modal letting them know that the coupon has been added successfully.

**A tag**

`<a href="#" class="btn btnDefault btnSmall" id="ajaxCoupon">Add coupon to cart and continue shopping <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></a>`

**Ajax**

```
        $('#ajaxCoupon').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $.get('ajaxAddCoupon', function(data){
                $('#successCoupon').foundation('reveal', 'open');
            });
        });
```

**controller & route**

```
    public function ajaxAddCoupon() {
        if(Request::ajax()) {
        Session::put('coupon', 'search10');

        return true;
    };
}

Route::get('ajaxAddCoupon', 'StoreController@ajaxAddCoupon');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this HTML:

```
<a href="{{ URL::to('ajaxAddCoupon') }}" class="btn btnDefault btnSmall" id="ajaxCoupon">Add coupon to cart and continue shopping <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></a>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#ajaxCoupon').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    $.get(url, function(data) {
        $('#successCoupon').foundation('reveal', 'open');
        console.log(data); // Log the data for testing
    });
});
```

Also, return a string instead of a boolean in your `ajaxAddCoupon()` function. I hope this works.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
$.get('ajaxAddCoupon', function(data){
    $('#successCoupon').foundation('reveal', 'open');
});
```

to:

```
$.get('/ajaxAddCoupon', function(data){
    $('#successCoupon').foundation('reveal', 'open');
});
```

**Edit** *- based on your reply*

Also change your method `ajaxAddCoupon` on your `StoreController` to return a string. i.e. instead of `return true;` change that to `return 'true';`

Comment: Doesn't work. I get an error: {"error":{"type":"UnexpectedValueException","message":"The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), \"boolean\" given."

Comment: If I got to the page it works perfectly fine. I haven't tried to dump auto yet.

Comment: Then change your method `ajaxAddCoupon` on your `StoreController` to return a string. i.e. instead of `return true;` change that to `return 'true';`

Comment: Still same thing. It's just returning the entire page.

Comment: Sorry ignore my comment about trying it in browser. It wont work, because your method only works when the request is ajax.

Comment: Can you remove the `if(Request::ajax()) {` check for now (whilst you debug this error) and then try to visit the URL in browser. Now you will know what the real error is.

Comment: Nothing. If I removed ajax() from the controller I can still access the URL with no problems. However, when accessing it through the page that has the ajax call..nothing happens. So it has to be something with that script.